# no assertions phpunit but there is

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a testcase for phpunit, but when it runs its reports there are no assertions.
There are clearly assertions. it looks no different to my other files. the number of tests reported is accurate if i add an remove tests but the assertions aren't running. whats the deal.

```
class DeferTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_Testcase     
{
    public function testNotRequiredNumberOfArgs()
    {
        $this->setExpectedException('DeferException');
        $defer = null;
        $defer = new Defer();
    }


    public function testRun()
    {
        $defer = new Defer($this, 'runTest', 1, 2, 3);
        $this->assertEquals($defer->run(4, 5, 6), array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
    }

    public function testClassNameRun()
    {
        $defer = new Defer('TestClass', 'run', 1, 2, 3);
        $this->assertEquals($defer->run(4, 5, 6), array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
    }

    public function runTest()
    {
        return func_get_args();

    }
}
```

Console output

```
$ phpunit test/core/DeferTest.php
PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.
... 
Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 5.50Mb 
OK (3 tests, 0 assertions)
```

Comment: Not sure if it is causing your problem, but it is not a good idea to do `setExpectedException('Exception')`.  Failed tests are marked by throwing a `FailedTestException`.  You should extend the `Exception` class and expect against that instead.

Comment: How do you run your test? And what is the console output?

Comment: Actually either `@expectedException` or `$this->setExpectedException()` should be used, so it's correct

Comment: @Schleis was referring to something else. PHPUnit doesn't accept `\Exception` class as an expectation in `setExpectedException`. You should use more specific exception class. I'm suprised that you didnt get any error because of that (maybe it was changed in 3.7 version).

Comment: What happen if you use `$this->assertTrue(true)` in each test instead of your actual tests?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to cyprian I found by asserting true in each case and commenting out the runTest method that the problem was the runTest method. It seems I was overriding a method from phpunit test case. Renaming the method fixed the problem.